# How to assign different labels to a set of classes using Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, label

Can someone guide me to do this in the best possible way using matlab.

i have files with names **001_g_01.sig...001_g_08.sig, 002_g_01.sig...002_g_010.sig, 003_g_01.sig...003_g_08, upto n files**. 
what i want to do is assigning labels to files belong to one user (**i.e.001_g_01.sig...001_g_08.sig as "User1", 002_g_01.sig...002_g_010.sig as "User2"** and so on).

i have the following code to read the files.

```
dirName= '/FolderPath';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'001_g_1.Sig') );
files = {files.name};

dirName1= '/FolderPath';
files1 = dir( fullfile(dirName1,'*.Sig') );
files1 = {files1.name};

for i=1:length(files)
fname = fullfile(dirName,files{i}); 
     %#  some calculation
  for j=i+1:length(files1)
    fname1 = fullfile(dirName1,files1{j});    
  %#  some calculation
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files1 =
        '001_g_01.sig'
        '001_g_08.sig'
        '003_g_01.sig'
        .
        .
```

If `files1` is a *cell* like above, then you can write:

```
userlabel = {'001','002','003'};
f = cellstr(files1);
for ii = 1:3
    result{ii} = strncmp(userlabel(ii),f,3);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
label = [repmat('User1',size(files,1),1); repmat('User2',size(files1,1),1) ];
```

This will create a array of labels containing `'User1'` and `'User2'`. If you need it separately, you can do it:

```
label1 = [repmat('User1',size(files,1),1)];
```

Comment: i am trying to compare the files in the following order for instance. (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,1) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,2) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) (3,3) and my target is to assign all (3,1) a separate label, all the (3,2) a separate label and so on.
In this particular example, 3 is the query file & 1,2,3 are the user samples(files) belonging to each user.

Comment: that why create an array of User1 based on the size of the (3,1) and create an array of User2 based on the size of (3,2). it will be easier that way, instead of using a for loop.